# Hide a field from a New Form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a form that uses a content type with fields to fill out. I am trying to hide one field from users so they wont fill it out. I use the drop down then edit columns and select and remove the check mark next to the field and save, but it keeps rendering the field on a new form. Any help on how to hide this field?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen in libraries with content types. Editing the form through the side panel commands has absolutely no effect. It may well be that content types override the form settings, but right now that is only my assumption. Content types have been around much longer than the modern forms, and there are many other things where legacy SharePoint features don't work well in the modern experience.

In such cases I go back to the content type definition and set the column to hidden.

If all else fails I resort to customising the form with PowerApps, where I have better control over the form elements.